# Assigning special characters to keyboards permanetly

Tags: windows, ubuntu, browser, keyboard-shortcuts, custom-keyboard

Is there a way in Windows 10 and/or Ubuntu to set new special characters in my keyboard?

I'm using a notebook, so I don't have Num Pad (or maybe I do but don't know yet). I have some characters that are fairly important, and I don't know how to type `ALT+xxxx` without the regular Num Pad. Googling for these characters every time is very cumbersome.

For instance, the left arrow character `←`, which is assigned as `Alt+2190`.

Is there a way to type it directly in the keyboard without the regular Num Pad, or maybe a code or software I could use to set it.

When I say Windows 10, think Notepad, but it could also be on OneNote or a browser, if there are an easier way on those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has keyboard shortcuts directly in settings. For Windows you can look into the third party app AutoHotKeys for keyboard shortcuts.

Also, try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/201671/1270397) for your numpad issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution: how should I proceed with this question on Stack Overflow?

The answer was it the Wikipedia entry [Unicode Input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows):

Some Windows' software accept the `Alt + x` solution:

- Open the Wordpad¹ software (it should come by default on Windows 10).
- Type the plain Unicode hex code in your text. Just the hex code, like `2190` for `←` or `f1` for `ñ`, no need for the `U+` or anything before it.
- Press the left ALT key plus the x character - `Alt + x`.
- The text should automatically change the hex code to the sign you want.
- Copy and paste the symbol into whatever you want it.

Not the perfect solution, but it is still better

¹ This may only work in specific software programs. It worked on Word, Wordpad, OneNote and Outlook, but not the simpler Notepad, neither Office online.